# i cant figure out my python game keep crashing

Tags: python, pygame, keyboard

please help when i press space, e, or f my game crashes but i cant find out why also can you help me make this dam block move upwards. please help me i will go insane if i cant figure this out.

`

```
# import the pygame module
import pygame
import keyboard
import time

xb = 30
yb = 670
x = 30
y = 670
o = 0

# Define the background colour
# using RGB color coding.
background_colour = (10,10,10)
  
# Define the dimensions of
# screen object(width,height)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 750),pygame.RESIZABLE)
  
# Set the caption of the screen
pygame.display.set_caption('shoter')
  
# Fill the background colour to the screen
screen.fill(background_colour)



def player():
    color = (40,40,45)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(x, y, 60, 60))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, color, ((x+60,y), (x+30,y-80), (x,y)))

    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, color, ((x-20,y+52.5), (x+30,y+70), (x+80,y+52.5)))
    color = (60,60,65)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect((x-70), (y+20), 200, 30))
    color = (40,40,45)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(x-70, y-20, 20, 40))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(x+110, y-20, 20, 40))

  
# Update the display using flip
pygame.display.flip()


# Variable to keep our game loop running
running = True

        

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Check for QUIT event      
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    if keyboard.is_pressed("a") or keyboard.is_pressed("w") or keyboard.is_pressed("left arrow"):
        print("left")
        screen.fill(background_colour)
        x = (x + -3.75)
        player()
        time.sleep(0.005)
        pygame.display.flip()

    if keyboard.is_pressed("d") or keyboard.is_pressed("s") or keyboard.is_pressed("right arrow"):
        print("right")
        screen.fill(background_colour)
        x = (x + 3.75)
        player()
        time.sleep(0.005)
        pygame.display.flip()

    if keyboard.is_pressed("space") or keyboard.is_pressed("f") or keyboard.is_pressed("e"):
        color = (255,0,0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(xb, yb, 60, 60))
        while (yb > -40):
            yb = yb + 5
            time.sleep(0.5)
        print("shot")
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

`

please help me ive tried to almost everything to make it work but everytime i press space it crashes

i think this is because of the while loop?

Comment: I suspect your stuck in your while loop `(yb > -40)` if yb is greater than -40 you add 5 to yb. this means that yb will only ever get bigger, and will never be under -40 so you will be stuck in the while loop forever

Comment: Image when you reach this while loop yb = -25. You will loop and add 5 to it, now its -20, then -15, then -10.......the number will forever be greater than -40 now

Answer (score 1):

In PyGame, the `0,0` co-ordinate is in the upper-left corner of the window.  In your game the player is positioned at the bottom, so the projectile moves up the display, going from a large y-coordinate to a smaller one, and eventually negative once off-screen.

As @Chris Doyle points out in a comment, your code has a tight loop where `yb` is *increased*, but then is tested for being `< -40`.  Since `yb` is already positive, this can never happen.  So your program is locking up at this point, as the loop exiting condition can never be satisfied.

Looking at your code, there's a few tweaks necessary for the projectile logic.

First it's best to try to paint everything on the screen from one place, then you're not re-painting (or accidentally erasing) items on every loop.

I also moved the logic of the bullet movement out into the main loop.  So pressing <kbd>space</kbd> only *starts* the bullet.  The movement happens when the main loop "sees" a bullet on the screen (when `firing` is True).

Other tweaks:  I don't have the `keyboard` module, so I ported this to standard PyGame keys.  And I took the liberty of renaming the `x,y` and `xb,yb` to `player_x, player_y` and `projectile_x, projectile_y`.  I hope that's OK.

```
# import the pygame module
import pygame
#import keyboard
import time

projectile_x = 30
projectile_y = 670
player_x = 30
player_y = 670
o = 0

# Define the background colour
# using RGB color coding.
background_colour = (10,10,10)
  
# Define the dimensions of
# screen object(width,height)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 750),pygame.RESIZABLE)
  
# Set the caption of the screen
pygame.display.set_caption('shoter')
  
# Fill the background colour to the screen
screen.fill(background_colour)



def player():
    color = (40,40,45)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(player_x, player_y, 60, 60))
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, color, ((player_x+60,player_y), (player_x+30,player_y-80), (player_x,player_y)))

    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, color, ((player_x-20,player_y+52.5), (player_x+30,player_y+70), (player_x+80,player_y+52.5)))
    color = (60,60,65)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect((player_x-70), (player_y+20), 200, 30))
    color = (40,40,45)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(player_x-70, player_y-20, 20, 40))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(player_x+110, player_y-20, 20, 40))

  
# Update the display using flip
pygame.display.flip()

# Is a projectile on screen?
firing = False

# Variable to keep our game loop running
running = True

        
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Check for QUIT event      
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    a_w_left  = keys[pygame.K_LEFT]  or keys[pygame.K_a] or keys[pygame.K_w]
    d_s_right = keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] or keys[pygame.K_d] or keys[pygame.K_s]
    e_f_space = keys[pygame.K_SPACE] or keys[pygame.K_e] or keys[pygame.K_f]

    if a_w_left:
        print("left")
        player_x = (player_x + -3.75)

    if d_s_right:
        print("right")
        player_x = (player_x + 3.75)

    if e_f_space:
        if ( not firing ):
            firing = True
            projectile_x = player_x
            projectile_y = player_y - 10
            print("shot")

    # repaint the screen
    screen.fill(background_colour)
    player()
    if ( firing ):
        color = (255,0,0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(projectile_x, projectile_y, 60, 60))
        projectile_y = projectile_y - 5
        if ( projectile_y < -60 ):
            firing = False   # bullet off screen

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick( 60 )   # limit FPS
```

Also, it's not good practice to use `time.sleep()` to control movement (etc.) in a PyGame program, because it blocks everything up.  It's better to use the real-time millisecond clock provided by `pygame.time.get_ticks()`.